# Como ativar animação do desenho SVG ao chegar na div dele?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Coloquei um arquivo em **SVG** para ter uma animação como se fosse criando ele em linhas (infelizmente no exemplo abaixo não está funcionando, mas no meu arquivo está.)

Com este código abaixo, assim que entro na página, a animação já começa e acontece até o desenho se completar.

Como eu faço para fazer a animação do desenho começar assim que eu chegar perto dele? Porquê o desenho fica perto do footer no meu site, e como a animação começa assim que eu entro na página, estou perdendo ela.

A animação é parecida com a deste site [aqui](https://gardenestudio.com.br/index.php), porém, ao invés de ser com scroll do mouse, é com a altura do scroll/página.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {


        var svg4 = new Walkway({
          selector: '#Layer_1',
          duration: 3500,
          redrawOnFocus: true

        });

        svg4.draw();

        document.addEventListener('dblclick', function() {
          svg.redraw();
          svg4.redraw();
        }, false);
      });
```

```css
svg {
 width: 157px;
 height: 157px;
 fill: red;
 margin-left: 130px;
}

svg path {
 stroke: #310B3B;
}

svg:not(:root) {
 overflow: visible;
}

path {
 fill: transparent;
}

svg > span {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
}

path, line, polyline {
 stroke: #fff;
 stroke-width: 1px;
}



polyline {
        stroke-width: 4px;
}

#Layer_1 path {
        stroke-width: 6.5px;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/ConnorAtherton/walkway/blob/master/src/walkway.js"></script>


<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
   <path d="M435.2,392.533c-23.526,0-42.667,19.14-42.667,42.667s19.14,42.667,42.667,42.667c23.526,0,42.667-19.14,42.667-42.667
    S458.726,392.533,435.2,392.533z M435.2,460.8c-14.114,0-25.6-11.486-25.6-25.6s11.486-25.6,25.6-25.6s25.6,11.486,25.6,25.6
    S449.314,460.8,435.2,460.8z"/>
   <path d="M494.933,387.029V102.4c0-9.412-7.654-17.067-17.067-17.067h-85.333c-9.412,0-17.067,7.654-17.067,17.067v230.4
    c0,4.71,3.814,8.533,8.533,8.533h17.067c4.719,0,8.533-3.823,8.533-8.533c0-4.71-3.814-8.533-8.533-8.533h-8.533V307.2h8.533
    c4.719,0,8.533-3.823,8.533-8.533s-3.814-8.533-8.533-8.533h-8.533v-17.067h25.6c4.719,0,8.533-3.823,8.533-8.533
    S422.852,256,418.133,256h-25.6v-17.067h8.533c4.719,0,8.533-3.823,8.533-8.533c0-4.71-3.814-8.533-8.533-8.533h-8.533V204.8
    h8.533c4.719,0,8.533-3.823,8.533-8.533s-3.814-8.533-8.533-8.533h-8.533v-17.067h8.533c4.719,0,8.533-3.823,8.533-8.533
    c0-4.71-3.814-8.533-8.533-8.533h-8.533v-17.067h25.6c4.719,0,8.533-3.823,8.533-8.533c0-4.71-3.814-8.533-8.533-8.533h-25.6
    V102.4h85.333v268.988c-12.22-8.201-26.88-12.988-42.667-12.988c-42.351,0-76.8,34.458-76.8,76.8
    c0,15.778,4.796,30.455,12.979,42.667H136.533v-85.333H153.6v25.6c0,4.71,3.823,8.533,8.533,8.533
    c4.71,0,8.533-3.823,8.533-8.533v-25.6h17.067v8.533c0,4.71,3.823,8.533,8.533,8.533s8.533-3.823,8.533-8.533v-8.533h17.067
    v8.533c0,4.71,3.823,8.533,8.533,8.533s8.533-3.823,8.533-8.533v-8.533H256v8.533c0,4.71,3.823,8.533,8.533,8.533
    c4.719,0,8.533-3.823,8.533-8.533v-8.533h17.067v25.6c0,4.71,3.814,8.533,8.533,8.533s8.533-3.823,8.533-8.533v-25.6h17.067
    v8.533c0,4.71,3.814,8.533,8.533,8.533c4.719,0,8.533-3.823,8.533-8.533V384c0-4.71-3.814-8.533-8.533-8.533H136.533
    c-9.89,0-17.067,7.177-17.067,17.067v85.333c0,9.89,7.177,17.067,17.067,17.067h250.496C400.213,505.583,416.964,512,435.2,512
    c42.351,0,76.8-34.458,76.8-76.8C512,416.964,505.583,400.222,494.933,387.029z M435.2,494.933
    c-32.93,0-59.733-26.795-59.733-59.733s26.803-59.733,59.733-59.733c32.93,0,59.733,26.795,59.733,59.733
    S468.13,494.933,435.2,494.933z"/>
   <path d="M443.733,59.733c0-4.71-3.814-8.533-8.533-8.533H102.4C102.4,22.963,79.437,0,51.2,0S0,22.963,0,51.2v409.6
    C0,489.037,22.963,512,51.2,512h42.667c4.71,0,8.533-3.823,8.533-8.533c0-4.71-3.823-8.533-8.533-8.533H51.2
    c-18.825,0-34.133-15.309-34.133-34.133c0-18.824,15.309-34.133,34.133-34.133s34.133,15.309,34.133,34.133
    c0,4.71,3.823,8.533,8.533,8.533c4.71,0,8.533-3.823,8.533-8.533V68.267h332.8C439.919,68.267,443.733,64.444,443.733,59.733z
     M85.333,422.741C76.262,414.601,64.324,409.6,51.2,409.6s-25.062,5.001-34.133,13.141V51.2
    c0-18.825,15.309-34.133,34.133-34.133S85.333,32.375,85.333,51.2V422.741z"/>
   <path d="M326.767,116.966c1.664,1.664,3.849,2.5,6.033,2.5c2.185,0,4.369-0.836,6.033-2.5c3.337-3.337,3.337-8.73,0-12.066
    l-17.058-17.058c-0.794-0.794-1.732-1.417-2.782-1.852c-2.082-0.862-4.437-0.862-6.519,0c-1.05,0.435-1.988,1.058-2.782,1.852
    L292.634,104.9c-3.337,3.337-3.337,8.73,0,12.066c3.337,3.336,8.73,3.336,12.066,0l2.5-2.5v197.734l-2.5-2.5
    c-3.337-3.336-8.73-3.336-12.066,0c-3.337,3.337-3.337,8.73,0,12.066l17.058,17.058c0.794,0.794,1.732,1.417,2.782,1.852
    c1.041,0.435,2.15,0.657,3.26,0.657c1.109,0,2.219-0.222,3.26-0.657c1.05-0.435,1.988-1.058,2.782-1.852l17.058-17.058
    c3.337-3.337,3.337-8.73,0-12.066c-3.336-3.336-8.73-3.336-12.066,0l-2.5,2.5V114.466L326.767,116.966z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Mas o desenho é tão pequeno, menor do que a altura da janela. Não dá tempo nem de rolar a tela.

Comment: vou reformular a pergunta, vai ser melhor começar a animação quando eu chegar na parte de baixo do site... 
quero tentar fazer isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insira um escutador que irá verificar quando o elemento estiver visível na tela, iniciando a animação:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

   var svg4 = new Walkway({
    selector: '#Layer_1',
    duration: 3500,
    redrawOnFocus: true
   });

   $(window).on("scroll", function(){
      var el = $('#Layer_1');
      var eleHeight = el.outerHeight(); // altura do elemento
      var eleTopo = el.offset().top; // distancia do elemento ao topo do documento
      var scrlTopo = $(window).scrollTop(); // quanto foi rolada a janela
      var distance = eleTopo-scrlTopo; // distancia do elemento ao topo da janela
      var altJanela = window.innerHeight; // altura da janela
      if(distance <= altJanela-(eleHeight/2)) {
         svg4.draw(); // inicia a animação
      }
   });

  document.addEventListener('dblclick', function() {
    svg.redraw();
    svg4.redraw();
  }, false);
});
```

**[Teste no JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwz8fjp7/1/)**

Comment: AAAA funcionou! Muuuuito obrigado :)